# Terraform script to create aws lexbot exception BadRequestException: The resource 'FallbackIntent' referenced

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-lex, aws-chatbot

I wrote terraform script to create a lexbot in AWS. It is a very simple script.
name, child_directed, abort_statment, intent are "Required" attributes for the "aws_lex_bot" resource.

It somehow throws error about the "intent" attribute
Error: creating Lex Bot (Chat_AutoReply): BadRequestException: The resource
'FallbackIntent' referenced in resource 'Chat_AutoReply' was not found. Choose another
resource.

```
   resource "aws_lex_bot" "chatbot-autoreply" {        
              name = "Chat_AutoReply"
              child_directed = false
              abort_statement {
                  message {
                      content_type = "PlainText"
                      content      = "Script aborted refer abort_statement"
                  }         
              }
              intent {
                   intent_name    = "FallbackIntent"
                   intent_version = "1"
              }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create [aws_lex_intent](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lex_intent) and then use that in `aws_lex_bot`, e.g.:

```
resource "aws_lex_intent" "fallback" {
   ...
}

resource "aws_lex_bot" "chatbot-autoreply" {        
              name = "Chat_AutoReply"
              child_directed = false
              abort_statement {
                  message {
                      content_type = "PlainText"
                      content      = "Script aborted refer abort_statement"
                  }         
              }
              intent {
                   intent_name    = aws_lex_intent.fallback.name
                   intent_version = "1"
              }
      }
```